# create new dimensions/hierarchies on the fly

Tags: mdx

I'm totally new to MDX language and curios if it capable of doing some sort of work.

There are calculated members that allows you to populate measure dimension with new data. But I have never met a reference to method that creates new dimensions with hierarchies.

For example, I have performed some cluster analysis and want to store result as hierarchy to make queries over calculated clusters. I'm searching for a function that takes predicate, apply it to all members in a slice and assign them new temporal dimension info. Something like the factor function in R.

Is this functionality available for MDX queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard way to create a dimension or hierarchies in MDX. Using calculated members is the usual way to go but this is not the same as creating a 'standard' hierarchy.

I don't know for others vendors but [icCube](http://www.iccube.com) introduced a couple of months [Categories](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/howto/categories.html) (also worth checking the [SubCube](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/SubCubeComplement.html) functions family). They allow to dynamically, after the cube has been loaded, build new hierarchies.

This is really handy when you're doing complex calculations or have many-to-many relations, as calculated members might quickly become a mess.